# Can SSRS pass a WCF service a parameter object?

Tags: wcf, reporting-services

I'm trying to get my SSRS report to call my WCF service, but when I do, the parameter is always null. It seems most of the examples I have been following do not use a parameter object, they would just use an int PONumber and int itemNumber parameter in my case. Is there a way to use an object parameter?

My service contract:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://schemas.XXX.com/WMS/WMSCustom/ReportingService")]
public interface IQAReportingServiceContract
{
    [OperationContract]        
    List<QAItemDetailResponse> GetQAItemDetail(QAItemDetailRequest request);
}
```

Request object:

```
[DataContract]
public class QAItemDetailRequest
{
    [DataMember]
    public int PONumber { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int itemNumber { get; set; }
}
```

My SSRS dataset query:

```
<Query>
<Method Name="GetQAItemDetail" Namespace="http://schemas.wegmans.com/WMS/WMSCustom/ReportingService">
<Parameters>
<Parameter Name="PONumber"></Parameter>
<Parameter Name="itemNumber"></Parameter>
</Parameters>
</Method>
<SoapAction>http://schemas.XXX.com/WMS/WMSCustom/ReportingService/IQAReportingServiceContract/GetQAItemDetail
</SoapAction>
</Query>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You should change your [DataContract] and [DataMember] attributes to [MessageContract] and [MessageBodyMember] respectively.  Also, it helps to set the MessageBodyMember "Order" parameter.